# How to find out whether the application is running or not using blue prism tool?

Tags: blueprism

Is it possible to find out whether the application is running/hanged/not yet started using blue prism tool.

Comment: what application?

Comment: Look at Utility-Environment VBO for some Actions that can determine things about processes?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Process Exists" Action in the "Utility - General" Object to find if it's running. You'll have to catch the exception and probably kill it if it's hanged.

Answer (score 0):

In utility general there is an option to check process(Process exist) and the existing process can be killed using utility environment(Kill Process).